# What's wrong with the omp declaration here? How to fix it?

Tags: c, parallel-processing, openmp

Here's my code, which allows different threads to compute conv2d and merge the results back to the result matrix.

```
#pragma omp parallel private(tid)
    float *gptr;
    gptr = malloc(M * M * sizeof(float) / NUMTHREADS);
    tid = omp_get_thread_num();
#pragma omp for
    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < M; j++)
        {
            float tmp = 0.;
            for (int k = 0; k < GW; k++)
            {
                int ii = i + k - W2;
                for (int l = 0; l < GW; l++)
                {
                    int jj = j + l - W2;
                    if (ii >= 0 && ii < M && jj >= 0 && jj < M)
                    {
                        tmp += float_m[k * M + l] * GK[ii * GW + jj];
                    }
                }
            }
            *(gptr + (i - tid * M / NUMTHREADS) * M + j) = tmp;
        }
    }
```

But the declaration `pragma omp parallel private(tid)` didn't work properly.
It gives the error message for float declaration next line:

```
\omp.c: In function 'main':.\omp.c:86:5: error: expected expression before 'float'
     float *gptr;     
     ^~~~~
```

Where did this go wrong and how to fix it?

Answer (score 4):

Your parallel region is longer than a single line, so you have to use curly braces:

```
#pragma omp parallel private(tid)
{
  //your code
}
```

UPDATE - a more precise answer with references:

From [OpenMP specification](https://www.openmp.org/spec-html/5.1/openmpse14.html#x59-590002.6) the syntax of the parallel construct is as follows:

```
#pragma omp parallel [clause[ [,] clause] ... ] new-line
        structured-block
```

The [structured block](https://www.openmp.org/spec-html/5.1/openmpsu2.html#x9-80001.2.2) is:

> an executable statement, possibly compound, with a single
> entry at the top and a single exit at the bottom, or an OpenMP
> construct.

The definition of [compound statement](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/statements):

> A compound statement, or block, is a brace-enclosed sequence of
> statements and declarations.

In your code

```
#pragma omp parallel private(tid)
    float *gptr;
```

`float *gptr;` is not an executable/compound statement/OpenMP construct, therefore you get an error message. You have to create a compound statement by putting your code between `{` and `}`.

Comment: Thanks! It works fine now. But it seems vscode doesn't recognize curly braces.

Answer (score 2):

I see three problems with your code.

1. Your immediate problem is that you need curly braces around the material of the `parallel` region.
2. Less importantly, considering putting a `collapse(2)` on the `i,j` loops.
3. But most importantly, are you sure that allocating `gptr` in the parallel region is what you want? It means that each thread creates its own copy, and which stays local to the parallel region. You probably want to allocate outside and pass the pointer in as shared.

Comment: Thanks for your help and it works fine now.